# Can I browse all the public Trello boards available?

Tags: trello

Is there a way to browse public boards on Trello?

I would be interested in how other users set up their boards and what they use it for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is not currently a way to browse all public boards.

Comment: Once we have more public boards and a better way to categorize them (with tags, for example), we may add more board browsing features. As it currently is, a public boards list will be a big, useless dump of boards that's impossible to navigate.

Comment: I would very much like to see this feature implemented. After that: A blog post (or Trello board) of the most interesting public Trello boards on the Internet.

Answer (score 13):

**Yes**, you can. With the help of [a google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Atrello.com#q=site:trello.com%2Fb%2F). Since boards are [crawlable](https://trello.com/robots.txt) you can search the Trello site on Google with the query `site:trello.com/b/`.

[image: but how do you expect me]

Answer (score 7):

Although you cannot browse all public boards you can search for keywords. For example: https://trello.com/search?q=trello will retrieve relevant Cards, Boards and Members.

Comment: As far as I can see (I just tested it) this search only concerns the boards "public" to oneself? I only find my own few cards, thus this is not helpful if we consider OP's question and intention.

Comment: It seems that sometime in the last year that behavior has changed. My current test also shows only my cards and not the public ones.

Comment: This request does not show any results

Answer (score 0):

In the sitemap.xml all public boards are listed.
See this: https://trello.com/sitemap.xml

Comment: The link is dead at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

Search this into Google:

```
{keyword you want here} site:trello.com
```

Replacing `{keyword you want here}` with your actual search term. Did this today and it worked great.

Answer (score -1):

I made a Google custom search engine that searches public trello boards
https://cse.google.com/cse?cx=013827739076658118304:ozxyffvt6ws