# Can I browse all the public JIRA boards available?

Tags: project-management, jira

Is there a way to browse public boards on Jira?

I would be interested in how other users set up their boards, how they use it & so on.

Note: it's the same question as [Can I browse all the public Trello boards available?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20158/can-i-browse-all-the-public-trello-boards-available) but for JIRA.

Comment: Yes. Go to Agile, Manage Boards. You can search by name or just browse